# OpenNMS events varbinds decode always showing the raw value between (parentheses)

Tags: variables, events, binding, decode, opennms

Is there a way to hide the raw value from a varbind that was decoded?

What I'm getting is:

```
deviceNotification trap received deviceRuleCode=browserOffline(7) notifObjType=trigger(1) notifObjSeverity=critical(6)
```

What i want is:

```
deviceNotification trap received deviceRuleCode=browserOffline notifObjType=trigger notifObjSeverity=critical
```

Obviously I'm passing the decoded varbinds parm[#] to the log message and/or description.

Any clue? Is it even supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After check the code, I've concluded that this is not supported.

The proof is here:
https://github.com/OpenNMS/opennms/blob/develop/features/events/daemon/src/main/java/org/opennms/netmgt/eventd/processor/expandable/ExpandableParameter.java#L75-L77

The token having the decoded value is always appended with the original value:

```
(...)
ret.append(decode.get(token).get(value));
ret.append("(");
ret.append(value);
ret.append(")");
(...)
```

.. and this happens for all the expanded values.